# How to parametrize an infinite line in a finite amount of time?

Tags: calculus

As the question stated, how do I traverse something like y=2x-3 with x and y fully ranging from negative infinity to positive infinity in... lets say a second? Is it possible?

Comment: Hint: consider the function $f(t) = \tan\left(\frac\pi 2 t\right)$, which gives a convenient starting position at $t=0$, and as $t \to \pm 1$, we have $f(t) \to \pm \infty$. Use this to parametrise $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Any line of the form $ax + by + c = 0$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. So you can just take any diffeomorphism $\gamma: (0, \varepsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$ and that will give you a parameterization which runs over your whole line in an arbitrarily small period of time.